# IOS SceneDelegate not invoked when extended in a different target

Tags: ios, swift, uiscenedelegate

I have an iOS project with the following targets:

```
SwiftExtensions (AppTarget) -> depends on Experience
Experience (StaticLibrary) -> depends on Lifecycle
Lifecycle (StaticLibrary)
```

I have defined the `SceneDelegate` in `Lifecycle` library:

```
public class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    
    // scene(_:willConnectTo:options:) is implemented in Experience

    // scene(_:openURLContexts:) is implemented in Experience

    // Other methods such as sceneWillEnterForeground(_:), sceneDidBecomeActive(_:) etc.
}
```

As shown above, `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` and `scene(_:openURLContexts:)` are not defined here.

In the `Experience` library, `SceneDelegate` is extended:

```
extension SceneDelegate {
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        
        NSLog("[Experience]: SceneDelegate.scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)")
        
        if (connectionOptions.urlContexts.isEmpty) {
            NSLog("[Experience]: Not launched using file!")
        } else {
            
            NSLog("[Experience]: Launched using file!")
            
            let urlContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext> = connectionOptions.urlContexts
            
            for (index, urlContext) in urlContexts.enumerated() {
                NSLog(String(format: "[Experience]: url[%d] = %@ ", index, urlContext.url.path()))
            }
        }
    }
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
        
        NSLog("[Experience]: SceneDelegate.scene(_:openURLContexts:)")
        
        for (index, urlContext) in URLContexts.enumerated() {
            NSLog(String(format: "[Experience]: url[%d] = %@ ", index, urlContext.url.path()))
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I tap the app icon, `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` is not invoked. When I tap an associated file type, `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` is not invoked, again. If app is running in background, and I foreground the app by tapping an associated file type, `scene(_:openURLContexts:)` is not invoked.

Basically, when I define these two methods outside the target, despite with public access modifier, iOS doesn't invoke my delegate methods defined in the other library. My understanding was, [Extensions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/extensions/#Methods) can be used to break up the class. What is missing here?